# customized figure and \includegraphics elemnt in tex4ht

Tags: graphics, floats, tex4ht

I try to configure the below xml structure through TeX4Ht

```
<fig id="fig_ch1_001">
<label>Figure 1.1</label>
<caption><title>Sample Text</title></caption>
<graphic xlink:href="demo.eps"/>
</fig>
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{demo.eps}
\caption{Sample Text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

CFG

```
\ConfigureEnv{figure}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi \EndP\HCode{<fig id="fig_ch\thechapter_\thefigure">}%
                      \HtmlParOff\bgroup \Configure{float}{\ShowPar}{}{}}
                     {\egroup\IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{</fig>}\ShowPar\par\HtmlParOn}
                     {}{}


\Configure{caption}{\HCode{<label>}}
                   {}
                   {\HCode{</label><caption><title>}}
                   {\HCode{</title></caption>}}%

\makeatletter
\Configure{IMG}
  {\HCode{<graphic xlink:href="\Gin@base\Gin@ext}}
  {}
  {"}
  {\HCode{"/>}}
  {}
\makeatother
```

I getting the correct output for figure environment and caption but in the image part, i am getting the wrong output as expected (i tried to modify in the `\Configure{graphics}`).

How to configure IMG part with the exact figure name `' ?

if we change `IMG' it will affect the equation image conversion?

Comment: the `eps` file is converted to `png`. do you want to use the generated `png`, or rather stick with original `eps`?

Comment: @michal no need to convert png, we need to retain as eps for later usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following configuration:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\usegraphics{%
  \HCode{<graphic xling:href="\Gin@base\Gin@ext" ></graphic>}%
  \special{t4ht+@File: \Gin@base\Gin@ext}%
}
\Configure{graphics}{\usegraphics}{}{}
\Configure{graphics*}{png}{\usegraphics}
\Configure{graphics*}{jpg}{\usegraphics}
\Configure{graphics*}{gif}{\usegraphics}
\makeatother
```

This configuration will `<graphic>` element at every `\includegraphics`, it won't do any conversions of the required image. You need to use `\Configure{graphics*}{extension}` for each graphic format you want to support.

This is the result:

```xml
   <fig id="fig_ch0_0">

<a 
 id="x1-21"></a>

<graphic xling:href="demo.eps" ></graphic>
<label>Figure 1</label><caption><title>Sample Text</title></caption>

   </fig>
```